# tomcat.service failed in a correct installation of Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, centos7, tomcat9

I've install Tomcat 9 in a Centos7 server. Everything seems to be ok but when I do :

> sudo systemctl status tomcat

I've a failed.state without error :

```
> août 31 14:27:55 server systemd[1]: Starting Tomcat 9 servlet
> container...
>     août 31 14:27:55 server startup.sh[102764]: Existing PID file found during start.
>     août 31 14:27:55 server startup.sh[102764]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
>     août 31 14:27:55 server systemd[1]: Started Tomcat 9 servlet container.
>     août 31 14:27:57 server systemd[1]: tomcat.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
>     août 31 14:27:57 server systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
>     août 31 14:27:57 server systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
```

Here is my tomcat.service file :

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat 9 servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/latest/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/shutdown.sh

SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I absolutely don't know what can I do to fix this error. Just in case and to be sure. During the installation, I've added a tomcat user to a tomcat group. Do I have to use my own username in the server?

if I add the user I'm using to log into the server into the group and add it inside tomcat.service, tomcat start but if I check the status, I've this error :

```
> ● tomcat.service - Tomcat 9 servlet container    Loaded: loaded
> (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mar. 2021-08-31 14:41:06
> CEST; 14s ago   Process: 103585
> ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/shutdown.sh (code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 103555
> ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh (code=exited,
> status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 103565 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> 
> août 31 14:41:05 server systemd[1]: Starting Tomcat 9 servlet
> container... août 31 14:41:05 server startup.sh[103555]:
> Existing PID file found during start. août 31 14:41:05 server
> startup.sh[103555]: Removing/clearing stale PID file. août 31 14:41:05
> server systemd[1]: Started Tomcat 9 servlet container. août 31
> 14:41:06 server systemd[1]: tomcat.service: control process
> exited, code=exited status=1 août 31 14:41:06 server
> systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state. août 31 14:41:06
> server systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
```

If I look at the catalina logs, I've this error :

> GRAVE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Impossible
> de créer le sokcet d'arrêt du serveur à l'adresse [localhost] et au
> port [8005] (port de base [8005] et offset [0])
> java.net.BindException: Adresse déjà utilisée (Bind failed)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:390)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:252)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:577)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:864)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:810)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
> 31-Aug-2021 15:11:31.145 INFOS [main]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Le gestionnaire de protocole
> ["http-nio-8080"] est mis en pause 31-Aug-2021 15:11:31.145 INFOS
> [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Arrêt du
> service [Catalina] 31-Aug-2021 15:11:31.161 INFOS [main]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Arrêt du gestionnaire de
> protocole ["http-nio-8080"] 31-Aug-2021 15:11:31.162 INFOS [1]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destruction du gestionnaire
> de protocole ["http-nio-8080"]

The problem is that with netstat, the port is only on listen/ I've used this command :

> netstat -an | grep 8005

And here is the result :

> tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*
> LISTEN

Comment: Check the logs in `/opt/tomcat/latest/logs`.

Comment: in the catalina logs, I can see this error (edited the first message). but if I do a netstat to check the port, it's on listen...

Comment: Another process (probably another Tomcat started manually) is already listening on port `8005`. Use `netstat -tnp | grep 8005` to see its PID.

Comment: That's strange because if I go in the bin folder, I can start it in bash with the startup.sh. Then, I can see the tomcat gui panel from http://server:8080 but if I type sudo systemctl status tomcat, I've a failure....

Comment: This exactly explains your problem: if you start Tomcat from your shell, the system service will fail, because the ports are already in use.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I execute the stop.sh and retry to start in command line, I have the same problem!

Comment: Kill all `java` processes. `stop.sh` will not work, since you didn't provide the environment variable `CATALINA_PID`, when you started the server from shell.